# gksudo Workaround for Leafpad and PCmanFM

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm, gksudo

I have read a lot of articles on how to work around the lack of gksudo in the latest *buntu releases.  Unfortunately, they've been tailored to applications I don't use like gedit, mousepad, nautilus, etc.

To make up for the lack, I created some aliases and launchers (shown below) for pcmanfm and leafpad that have worked great so far, but I'd like to have a **sanity check to make sure they are safe to use.**

Also, I don't really understand DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY.  I just know that they are environmental variables that need to be included.  **Do they refer back to specific files that I can look at?**

Following are the aliases and launchers:

This is used with pcmanfm or leafpad:

```
alias gksudo2='sudo -H pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY'
```

This opens the hosts file for editing:

```
alias hosts2='sudo -H pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY leafpad /etc/hosts'
```

This is for opening pcmanfm as root:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=pcmanfm-rootpk
Type=Application
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/PNG Alphabetical Icons/128/p_orange.png
Exec=sudo -H "pkexec env DISPLAY\=\$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY\=\$XAUTHORITY" pcmanfm %U 
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Utility</code>
```

This is used for editing the hosts file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Keywords=hosts file
Name=HostsFileLauncher-rootpk
Comment=hosts
Exec=sudo -H leafpad /etc/hosts pkexec env "DISPLAY\=\$DISPLAY" "XAUTHORITY\=\$XAUTHORITY" 
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/PNG Alphabetical Icons/128/h_orange.png
Terminal=true
NoDisplay=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain
Categories=Utility</code>
```